# How to Trim a string from Left

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a string like this in my MS Access database

```
abcdefg\1234567890
```

I need to query the database and get a string like this

```
1234567890
```

so I need to trim this everything left of the `\` character. How would I do this using sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Mid` function with `InStr`:

```
Mid([X], InStr([X], "\") + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`

the position to begin trimming is the location of the '\' character.

Comment: Access's `SUBSTRING` function is called `MID$()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use MID and InStr :)

=MID(col, Instr(col, "\") + 1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to combine the use of three functions. You use MID as a basis, then you need FIND() to locate the position of the "/" and finally you need len to calculate how many you should take. 
MID has three parameters; string, starting position, how many characters.
It should be something like:  MID(column, find(column, "/"), len(column) - find(column,"/").

Comment: The last parameter of `Mid` is optional; if you omit it, the function returns the remainder of the string.